# Qual a função do Appium no android studio?

Tags: android

Para que serve esse Appium e Quais as funcionalidades dele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Appium](http://appium.io/), como diz no próprio site, é uma ferramenta *open source* e multiplataforma para criação de testes automatizados para aplicações nativas, híbridas e websites mobile.

> Quais as funcionalidades dele?

O Appium permite que você crie testes automatizados. Os testes servem para impedir que alguns campos aceitem datas como `29/fev` em anos que não são bissextos; fornece informações importantes que deveriam estar na tela mas não estão; erros de português em campos, mensagens etc.

Existem vários tipos de testes automatizados que podem ser feitos: unitários, integração, funcionais, aceitação. Veja aqui [este artigo do Elias Nogueira](http://www.qualister.com.br/blog/automacao-de-testes-mobile-com-appium---parte-1) que ensina como criar testes usando Appium.

Além do Appium, existem outras formas de [**testar o aplicativo**](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html?hl=pt-br), como indica na documentação do Android.

**Referência**

- [Appium](http://appium.io/)

Comment: Show de bola , valeu